# Loading a custom CSS Handler for Node.JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I have a basic Node.JS server setup as I'm doing a new project for work. I've written and optimizer function that strips unnecessary things like tabs, newlines and comments from HTML, JavaScript and CSS.

For some odd reason when I added my `<link type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap.mins.css">` to my head it's not loading or showing up in the Google Network tab.

The main HTML is loading just not the CSS.

**Server:**

```
app.get("/css/:file",function(req,res){
    logger.log("CSS File");
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/css"});
    res.write(fs.readFileSync(appRoot + "/css/" + req.params.file,"utf8").optimize());
    res.end();
});
```

There is no nested CSS files, all in one directory. This, in theory, should work but it isn't. It loads and is processed when I go to the direct URL. Just not from the ***LINK***.

[image: HTML Outline from Google Console Elements Tab.]

Loading the HTML Page:
[image: The HTML did NOT load the CSS file.]

Loading the CSS Directly; It does preprocess:
[image: The RAW Link Loaded and was preprocessed.]

Comment: As a side question: Why would you optimize the file everytime it is requested?

Comment: Should I just write a bash script to run on the Production server and optimize it when an update is pulled live? I have no formal training in programming just been doing it for 12 years.

Comment: Something like that. Optimizing it every time can't be good performance wise. Do it once, cause currently it's an unnecessary redundant task.

Comment: This would still be a good idea in theory. Then custom CSS compilers could be made, but I get where you're coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after further study I found that my code above did work. I had 1 slight failure though. I missed the `rel` tag in the actual link. The CSS loads fine and optimized after this.

```
<head>
    <title>In House Tool</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
```